# Is it possible or a good idea to hold react components inside reducer and based on action pass the component to the container?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to build a generic dialog, all its responsibility is to show the model dialog and the content inside the dialog. However i want to pass the content via reducer based on the action. So if the dispatched action is to display a list of radio buttons in the modal dialog the reducer based on switch will return a react component which gets rendered in the dialog or may the dispatched action is to display a table with rows and columns and the reducer will return another component which then gets rendered in the modal dialog.

Is this possible or a good idea? if not how can I build a generic dialog where the content to display is passed in dynamically?

my reducer will be something like this

```js
import {LOAD_RADIOBUTTONS} from "../actions/radiobutton_action";
import {LOAD_TABLE} from "../actions/table_action";
import LoadRadioButtons from "../components/LoadRadioButtons";
import LoadTableData from "../components/LoadTableData";


const INITIAL_STATE = { data: null, openDLG: false, loadData: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {


    switch(action.type){
        case LOAD_RADIOBUTTONS :
            return { data: action.payload, openDLG: true, LoadData: LoadRadioButtons };
        case LOAD_TABLE :
            return { data: action.payload, openDLG: true, LoadData: LoadTableData };

        default: return state;

    }
}
```

Now the container will get data from the reducer and the component it needs to render and will render it.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to hold a component in your Redux state, as components are just functions, whether they are class-based components or functional components. However, it might be better to pass the component you want to render down as a prop, as holding the component to render in your store will probably make your state merging logic more complicated.

For instance, the parent component of the component which will do the dynamic rendering might read from the Redux store, and based on the state of the Redux store, choose one of many components to pass down as a prop to its child. This seems like a better approach to me, as it stays within the Redux good practice of making components pure functions of their props and state, *and* it keeps your Redux store data model cleaner.